# Trouble with Case Command in bash

Tags: bash

I want to match a string that follows this pattern:

> It should start with an a `A`, `K`, `N` or `W` then can be followed by a digit or letters in the range `a-zA-Z`, and if it has a letter as the second letter a digit follows it and then it can have 1, 2 or 3 letters.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function callsign() {
    echo -e "Insert your call sign"
    while true; do
    read input
    case $input in
        [Aa,Kk,Nn,Ww][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] ) break;;
        [Aa,Kk,Nn,Ww][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z] ) break;;
        [Aa,Kk,Nn,Ww][a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] ) break;;
        [Aa,Kk,Nn,Ww][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] ) break;;
        [Aa,Kk,Nn,Ww][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] ) break ;;
        * ) echo "please insert valid call sign.";;
    esac
    done
    clear
}
callsign
```

I'm having problems because I have too many cases (and yet not including them all). How can I solve this in a better way?

Comment: Fixed your she-bang (`#!/bin/bash`) as part of the edit

Comment: Your glob `[Aa,Kk,Nn,WW]` looks suspicious (and while not syntactically wrong, probably shows some misconceptions)… what are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: I'm curious About the Seemingly Arbitrary use Of capitalization In the Question.

Comment: it needs to be exact to verify be cause i only allow a,k,n,w and in my actual script it has #!/bin/bash

Comment: Yeah, for sure... but can you give us some examples of what `$input` is valid and what `$input` is invalid?

Comment: it also can be capitalized or lower case or mixed because i filter out that later

Comment: Still very interesting, but Can You give Us some Examples of Valid call Signs and Invalid call Signs?

Comment: an example would be Ai0AA or K1ttl or ww1eda an invalid would be like a1aaaa or B01b C0C

Comment: The first two work, not the third one because you don't have a lowercase `w` in your glob. By the way, do you also want a comma as the first character?

Comment: I fixed the case on the the W's  and i don't want a comma as the first char

Comment: So remove the comma in the first part of your globs. If you want us to help you further, you'll have to describe more precisely the language you're trying to match…

Comment: can you explain  what you mean

Comment: do you mean `[AaKk,Nn,Ww][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z] ) break;;` like this

Comment: Remove _all_ the commas. What is a _call sign?_

Comment: that is an identifier that is like a username except it is only allowed to be one of those strings to make sure there a real user also i tried removing all the commas and it doesn't recognize and of the valid inputs

Comment: But we have no idea what should be a valid input and what shouldn't be a valid input, so we can't help you. You have to _describe_ the valid inputs you want.

Comment: an example would be Ai0AA or K1ttl or ww1eda an invalid would be like a1aaaa or B01b C0C

Comment: For crying out loud, can you _describe_ it? something like: it should start with an `A` or a `K` or a `N` or a `W`, be followed by a digit and then followed by 3 letters… we're not psychic you know!

Comment: So I should start With an Any A K N W then can be followed by a Number or Letters a-z and if it Has a letter as the second letter a number follows it and then it can have 1-3 letters

Comment: There you go! _this is what you should include in your question!_

Comment: sorry i have only used this web site to ask twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I should start With an Any A K N W then can be followed by a Number or Letters a-z and if it Has a letter as the second letter a number follows it and then it can have 1-3 letters

There are several possibilities to do the match. One of them is to use a regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch

callsign() {
   while true; do
      read -ep "Insert your call sign: " input
      if [[ $input =~ [aknw](|[a-z])[0-9][a-z](|[a-z](|[a-z])) ]]; then
         break
      else
         echo "please insert valid call sign."
      fi
   done
   echo "it works!"
}
callsign
```

Another possibility is to use an extended glob:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nocasematch extglob

callsign() {
   while true; do
      read -ep "Insert your call sign: " input
      if [[ $input = [aknw]@(|[a-z])[0-9][a-z]@(|[a-z]@(|[a-z])) ]]; then
         break
      else
         echo "please insert valid call sign."
      fi
   done
   echo "it works!"
}
callsign
```

Note the use of `nocasematch` so that it deals with lower/uppercase.

Comment: `++` for using re's than redundant glob syntaxes.